# Setup AWS API gateway custom authorizers in serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I need to add AWS API gateway custom authorizer to a Lambda function. Currently I have added the authorizer for each endpoint. As in the following `serverless.yml`.

**serverless.yml**

```
service: test-service

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs6.10
    stage: dev
    region: us-east-1

functions:
    bff:
        handler: app.handler
        events:
            - http:
                path: /home
                method: get
                cors: true
                authorizer :
                    arn: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxx:function:token-verifier
                    resultTtlInSeconds: 0
                    identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
                    identityValidationExpression: '.*'
```

> **How can I add the custom authorizer to the entire lambda function
>   rather than adding separately to each endpoint?**

Comment: Check out this : https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3828

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confusing the boundary between AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda. It's not your fault. *Serverless Framework* is that good that it almost blurs those two things.

---

Strictly speaking, AWS Lambda Functions **DO NOT** need custom authorizers.

Authorizers are used for securing API Gateway endpoints **NOT** for AWS Lambda functions.

Therefore, you need to define the authorizer **for each endpoint** you need to require authorization for.

---

If you're after making your `serverless.yml` more concise by not repeating the authorizer definition multiple times, you can define it once and just reference it in your endpoints.

```
service: test-service

custom:
    authorizer:
        arn: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxx:function:token-verifier
        resultTtlInSeconds: 0
        identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        identityValidationExpression: '.*'

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs6.10
    stage: dev
    region: us-east-1

functions:
    bff:
        handler: app.handler
        events:
            - http:
                path: /home
                method: get
                cors: true
                authorizer: ${self:custom.authorizer}
```